# Can't access `AnyOrder` named parameters

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Straight from [`AnyOrder` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnyOrder.html)

```
StringCases["abc123 456def", 
   AnyOrder[LetterCharacter .., DigitCharacter ..]
]
(* {"abc123", "456def"} *)
```

But if we name the parameters only the explicitly written ordering matches (e.g letters then digits)!

```
StringCases["abc123 456def",  
    a : AnyOrder[l : LetterCharacter .., d : DigitCharacter ..] :> {a, {l, d}}
]
(* {{"abc123", {"abc", "123"}}, {"456def", {"", ""}}} *)
```

Is this the expected behavior? Am I missing something? This was tested on OS X 10.10.5, Mathematica 10.3.0

Comment: I can confirm this for 10.3 on Win 7 Pro 64 bit.  It seems like a bug.  I'll raise the ante by suggesting you try `StringCases["abc123 456def  789ghi", a : AnyOrder[d : DigitCharacter .., l : LetterCharacter ..] :> {a, {d, l}}]`.  You will notice that it only replaces the named patterns in `AnyOrder` when their order in the string matches the order of the patterns as listed in `AnyOrder`.

Comment: Same for 10.4, Win 10.

Comment: @Edmund Yes! That's what I had meant with "only the typed ordering matches!" I'll reword it a bit

Answer (score 5):

***tl;dr***: The behavior of `AnyOrder` observed by the OP might be related to the way `StringExpression` handles named patterns. A work around with `SequencesCases` and `OrderlessPatternSequence` can be used in principle for simple string patterns.

---

**Analysis**

It may be the case that `AnyOrder` is translated into a form of `Alternatives` and `StringExpression` (not necessarily at top-level) where the names of the patterns are lost. This can be seen by noticing that the second output can be obtained with

```
(* Input 1 *)

StringCases["abc123 456def", 
            a : ( (l : LetterCharacter .. ~~ d : DigitCharacter ..) | 
                  (DigitCharacter .. ~~ LetterCharacter ..)
                ) :> {a, {l, d}}
]

(* {{"abc123", {"abc", "123"}}, {"456def", {"", ""}}} *)
```

The alternative, where the pattern names are kept in the second argument of `Alternatives`, makes `StringExpression` throw warnings for the first evaluation and, more importantly, change the resulting expression:

```
(* Input 2 *)

StringCases["abc123 456def", 
            a : ( (l : LetterCharacter .. ~~ d : DigitCharacter ..) | 
                  (d : DigitCharacter .. ~~ l : LetterCharacter ..)
                ) :> {a, {l, d}}
]

StringExpression::cond: Warning: restrictions on pattern variable d in d:(DigitCharacter..) 
 are ignored as they are not associated with the first occurrence of d.

StringExpression::cond: Warning: restrictions on pattern variable l in l:(LetterCharacter..) 
 are ignored as they are not associated with the first occurrence of l.

(* {{"abc123", {"abc", "123"}}} *)
```

So the issue may boil down to the way `StringExpression` handles pattern, provided of course that the initial assumption about a translation was correct. This would explain why the pattern names are lost for another order of the given string patterns.

**StringExpression warnings**

The warnings seen above happen with simpler inputs where no `Alternatives` is involved:

```
(* Input 3 *)

StringCases["aa", a : LetterCharacter ~~ a : LetterCharacter :> a]

StringExpression::cond: Warning: restrictions on pattern variable a in a:LetterCharacter 
are ignored as they are not associated with the first occurrence of a.

(* {"a"} *)
```

The second pattern restriction, here `LetterCharacter`, is ignored in the matching, which means that changing it to different pattern object, such as `DigitCharacter`, will still work:

```
(* Input 4 *)

StringCases["aa", a : LetterCharacter ~~ a : DigitCharacter :> a]

StringExpression::cond: Warning: restrictions on pattern variable a in a:DigitCharacter 
are ignored as they are not associated with the first occurrence of a.

(* {"a"} *)
```

We can therefore assume that `Inputs 3` and `4` are viewed for the evaluation process as

```
StringCases["aa", a : LetterCharacter ~~ a_ :> a]

(* {"a"} *)
```

Applying this assumption to `Input 2`, we can understand why we obtained the output `{{"abc123", {"abc", "123"}}}`

```
StringCases["abc123 456def", 
            a : ( (l : LetterCharacter .. ~~ d : DigitCharacter ..) | 
                  (d_ ~~ l_)) :> {a, {l, d}}
]

(* {{"abc123", {"abc", "123"}}} *)
```

**Further remarks and possible work around**

It has to be noted that when using the following counterpart of `Input 2`,

```
SequenceCases[Characters["abc123 456def"], 
               a : ( {l : _?LetterQ .., d : _?DigitQ ..} | 
                     {d : _?DigitQ .., l : _?LetterQ ..}
                   ) :> {StringJoin[a], {StringJoin[l], StringJoin[d]}}
]

(* {{"abc123", {"abc", "123"}}, {"456def", {"def", "456"}}} *)
```

we obtain the expected output. Re-expressing this input by means of `OrderlessPatternSequence`, which brings the expression closer to OP's second input, also yields the same output

```
SequenceCases[Characters["abc123 456def"], 
       a : {OrderlessPatternSequence[l : _?LetterQ .., d : _?DigitQ ..]
           } :> {StringJoin[a], {StringJoin[l], StringJoin[d]}}
]

(* {{"abc123", {"abc", "123"}}, {"456def", {"def", "456"}}} *)
```

This seems to imply that `OrderlessPatternSequence` translates to `Alternatives` (not necessarily at top-level), which makes the initial assumption about `AnyOrder` plausible. So in the end, the behavior you mentioned might indeed be related to the way `StringExpression` handles patterns.

As a last remark, using `OrderlessPatternSequence` in the way above could be a workaround. But this is unfortunately viable to some extent only, since translating other string pattern specifications, such as for instance `PunctuationCharacter`, `WordBoundary` and `Whitespace`, even though perhaps feasible, complicates the picture.